# $save().then on Angular $resource doesn't wait for the service response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some controller and a function called to obtain some value from a REST WCF web service:

```
fooBar.controller('fooCtrl',
            function fooCtrl($scope, $http, $resource) {
                $scope.someOnClickEvent = function () {
                GetSomething('a','b','c');
            }
        }
);

function GetSomething($scope, $resource, a, b, c) {
    var ServiceHandle = $resource('some/addr');
    var serviceHandle = new ServiceHandle();

    serviceHandle.a = a;
    serviceHandle.b = b;
    serviceHandle.c = c;

    serviceHandle.$save().then(function (result) {
        console.log('So response should be ready');
        $scope.result = result.ValueFromService;
    });
}
```

As far as I know `$save()` returns promise and function inside `.then` should be called right after response is returned by the server. In my case it's called imediately.

If service returns true I'm going to show some popup, so I need this value to be returned before conditional instruction is executed.

Version of Angular is 1.4.9.

Comment: The documentation does indeed say instance actions return a promise, though the source looks less clear cut (the actual return is `return result.$promise || result`. The actions also take both success and error callbacks so if the promise isn't working for you maybe you could try those.

Comment: Thank you @Duncan. I was wrong, .then works like a charm. It's just my lack of education in a field of asynchronous programming ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've analysed code and its behavior and I'm wrong obviously. Maybe I should delete this question, but I believe it can help someone to understand similar problems.

Function inside `.then` is in fact called after a response comes from the server. It can be verified using for instance Chrome's developer tools (namely tab network).

However if just after calling GetSomething function we want to access a `$scope.result` we are making a great mistake. `$scope.result` will be `undefined` as long as function inside `.then` won't be executed. To use a value returned from a service we must do it inside `.then` function or in a function called by it.

Comment: What you should do is return a promise from GetSomething: specifically return the result of `serviceHandle.$save().then()` and then any code that needs to wait for completion can do so. Basically make every async function return a promise and you can then either ignore it or use it.